# Does a reroll let you choose the higher roll?

Tags: fate-core, invokes

When invoking an aspect in Fate Core for a reroll, and the second roll is worse than the first, can you go with the first roll? Do rerolls in Fate work like rolling with advantage in D&D, or are you stuck with the second roll without spending another Fate point?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you reroll you're stuck with the new result. You don't get to pick the highest of the two; the previous roll's gone.

It's for this reason [the authors recommend only rerolling on a –3 or –4](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/invoking-compelling-aspects#the-reroll-vs.-the-+2) in a sidebar on Fate Core page 68:

> #### The reroll vs the +2
>
> Rerolling the dice is a little riskier than just getting the +2 bonus, but has the potential for greater benefit. We recommend you reserve this option for when you’ve rolled a –3 or a –4 on the dice, to maximize the chance that you’ll get a beneficial result from rerolling. [The odds are better that way.](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/taking-action-dice-ladder#the-math-behind-the-dice)

The simple version of the odds at that point is that your chance of rolling –3 or –4 (again) is so vanishing small (~6%) you're nearly guaranteed to *at least* upgrade to –2, and the odds of getting at least a +0 aren't bad (~61%).

Being able to choose between the two sounds like a viable stunt though, or at least a half-stunt effect. Here's how I might handle it:

> *Quantum re-entanglement goggles.* You get a +1 to Create Advantage with Lore when discerning scientific facts. In addition when you spend a fate point to reroll any science-themed Lore roll, you may keep your choice of the new or old result.